# How to get numbers outside ranges

Tags: python

How can I write a function that asks the user to specify multiple set of numbers and return the numbers outside of these ranges?

Let's say I want the numbers that are not included in 3-8 and 11-15 within the range 1 to 20, therefore it would have to return 1-2,9-10,16-20

Comment: Do you want the user to enter a range and a set of ranges that should be excluded from the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first, last = tuple(map(int, input("what are first and last numbers?").split(" ")))
data = set(range(first, last + 1))
while True:
    inp = input("entre set: ")
    if inp == "":
        break
    first, last = tuple(map(int, inp.split(" ")))
    numbers_set = set(range(first, last + 1))
    data -= numbers_set
    
data = tuple(data)
last_var = data[0]
res = str(data[0])

for var in data[1:]:
    if var != last_var + 1:
        res += "-" + str(last_var) + ", " + str(var)
    last_var = var
res += "-" + str(last_var)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

A fun way is to use [set operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```py
>>> r = set(range(1,21)) # numbers 1-20
>>> r
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}
>>> q = set(range(3,9)) | set(range(11,16)) #numbers 3-8 and 11-15
>>> q
{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14}
>>> r-q # Difference of sets (elements in r that are not in q)
{1, 2, 9, 10, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}
```